# Прозрачные объекты за объектом с кастомным шейдером

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите способ "распространения" эффекта шейдера на прозрачные объекты, находящиеся за объектом, к которому применен этот шейдер. Проблема в том, что они даже не рендерятся. Если сменить очередь или убавить альфу у объекта с шейдером, то можно увидеть прозрачный объект, но без эффекта. Unity 2023.2.13f1 URP.
[image: Часть объекта не видна]

[image: Убавлена альфа у стекла]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, путем добавления feature "Render Objects" в настройки рендера и переносом шейдера на отдельный слой.
В параметрах "Render Objects" указал событие и фильтр. Работает отлично даже с WebGL.

[image: Выставленных параметров]

[image: Указанных в фильтре слои]